# Back-face Culling Performance

Tags: opengl

I've always been wondering about this:

Is is there a performance impact if I render **only front facing polygons**, while back-face culling is enabled?
Should I rather disable it in such a situation?
Or is this something that depends on the OpenGL implementation?
I can imagine that rendering polygons with disabled back-face culling will be faster on software implementations. But on hardware?

**EDIT**
To clear things up: There will never be any back facing polygons in my scene. Back-face culling will never cull anything.

Comment: Well, if you *know* you render only front facing polygons, disabling backface culling will not make this slower, so just disable it and don't care if it wasn't actually needed ;)

Comment: Why don't you just benchmark it yourself, like rendering x amount of front facing polygons on the screen both where back-face culling is enabled and disabled, and then you can see the answer.

Comment: Determining polygon winding order in OpenGL is a very simple process. It uses the post-projected vertices (hence sometimes if you use a weird projection matrix you have to switch your front polygon winding), instead of more expensive side calculations that would require the calculation of polygon normals. Enabling it will reduce the number of filled fragments, so it should always give a performance _increase_. You can even do face culling on the CPU, this used to be common on the PC but is now mostly reserved for the CELL processor's SPEs on the PS3 where it is still a viable optimization.

Comment: Because all polygons have a front and a back face unless you cull one or the other.

Comment: Because if you disabled back-face culling you would no longer be only rendering front facing polygons.

Comment: Sorry, but your wording sucks in that case. "... if I render only front facing polygons with back-face culling enabled?" means "... if I render only front facing polygons as a result of back-face culling enabled?"

Comment: It was not my first language either, by the way. Which is why I take everything I read literally and have trouble with vaguely written statements. In any case, there is no need to get all angry. Now that we have cleared up what you mean, in a hardware implementation back-face culling should not introduce any measurable overhead during primitive assembly. In software, perhaps but again it comes down to the winding of post-projected vertices and it does not require the computation of a surface normal, so it is cheaper than you would intuitively think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the winding of a primitive must be determined (for the rasterization process) regardless of culling being enabled or not, back face culling comes practically for free. So you can leave it on. Switching culling state itself is a no-brainer for a OpenGL implementation. It doesn't affect any caches, pipeline state or other things which can have a huge performance impact.

Comment: Thank you alot for that answer! That's exactly what I've been looking for.